# Integrating Signals

Tags: analog, analysis

Yes that simple,

Can someone explain what the main purpose is behind integrating an incoming signal?
What advantages does this offer over lets say reading the voltage directly with an A/D?
How does this function as a low-pass filter?

Ive seen the schematics and understand how they work, just trying to fill the gaps in my mental picture.

Thanks guys

Comment: It seems like you are asking three different questions, there are many reason you may want to integrate a signal. But how it is related to your other questions I am not sure. Perhaps providing some more information would be insightful.

Comment: Probably reflects the mental gap I'm having ( :D but also :/ ).  I read that phase-noise jitter etc can be filtered out with many samples using integration, Im trying to understand how the area is used to filter this phase error or for that sake the grand difference between reading values directly. Hope that helps, thanks in advance

Comment: Ahh, I think I see now. I'll answer below.

Comment: I would also suggest editing your question to reflect the increased specificity. For example title: Integration as it applies to reading Phase Noise and then reword the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration, as you probably know, is a widely used effect and has many applications.

**As it applies to determining Phase-Noise:**

First we should distinguish the difference between "Phase Noise" and "Jitter". [Phase noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_noise) in short, refers to random fluctuations in the phase of a signal. While [jitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jitter) refers to random *time domain* fluctuations.

Now that we know the difference between the two, let's take a closer look at "phase noise" and determine why you would need an integral. While there are varying definitions of how to obtain a measurement of phase noise, every definition agrees on the fact that phase noise is read by determining the *[power spectral density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density)* of the signal.

Finally, let's look at the definition of power spectral density and it will become clear why you need the integral of the signal. While there are a few ways to determine the power spectral density of a signal, all of them involve the same symbol at some point... You guessed it: $$\int$$

**So in review, you need to take the integral because:**

1. To read the phase noise, you must know the power spectral density of the signal
2. To know the power spectral density, you must take the integral of the signal

Thus, we arrive back at the conclusion which Scott tersely led us to. You take the integral of the signal, because you need the integral of the signal.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost tautological.  One integrates a signal because one needs the integral of a signal.  There are many reasons why.  A common one may be to avoid steady state following error in a control loop. Indeed, a 
low pass filter can be thought of as a leaky integrator.

Comment: Alternatively, an integrator can be thought of as a 1st order low pass filter in the limit as the pole frequency goes to zero while the gain goes to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, integration is used to bring an extremely low-level signal up to the level where it can be detected at all. For example, integrating a picoamp-level photocurrent to get a measureable voltage.

Comment: Hm, I think I understand, because in most applications we dont just integrate as we have an opamp which has gain right? Thx again :)